# Unexpected errors while testing Python code with doctest

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

I'm using [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html) to test my code, and I'm getting unexpected error while testing a simple function which produces two lines of text output. Why?

Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04. Same bug can be observed with Python 2.7 and Python 3.9.

Test program (saved as `doctest-bugs.py`):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def testme():
    """
    Emit test message.

    >>> testme()
    First line (no leading spaces)
     Second line (one leading space)
    """
    return """First line (no leading spaces)
 Second line (one leading space)"""
```

Regular run:

```
$ python3 doctest-bugs.py
```

Testing with `doctest`:

```
$ python3 -m doctest doctest-bugs.py 
**********************************************************************
File "/home/filip/doctest-bugs.py", line 7, in doctest-bugs.testme
Failed example:
    testme()
Expected:
    First line (no leading spaces)
     Second line (one leading space)
Got:
    'First line (no leading spaces)\n Second line (one leading space)'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in doctest-bugs.testme
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

All the strings are verbatim, and the single leading space should be recognized without any problem according to module documentation.

Comment: Here's a hint: `print(testme())` is a red herring. Look at the actual return value: `'First line (no leading spaces)\n Second line (one leading space)'`. The function doesn't print anything. LMK if you don't get it.

Comment: @wjandrea whatever animal it is, it does not affect the case. Anyways - removed for clarity.

Comment: Oh haha, "red herring" is an idiom that means "a distracting piece of information".

Comment: related Python bug -> https://bugs.python.org/file49066

Comment: Wait what, you filed a bug for this? This isn't a bug; you're misunderstanding how strings work. I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function doesn't produce two lines of output; it returns a string that contains two lines.

```
>>> testme()
'First line (no leading spaces)\n Second line (one leading space)'
```

Maybe you're confusing returning with printing.

```
>>> print(testme())
First line (no leading spaces)
 Second line (one leading space)
```

Here's a working example:

```
def testme():
    """
    >>> testme()
    'First line (no leading spaces)\\n Second line (one leading space)'
    >>> print(testme())
    First line (no leading spaces)
     Second line (one leading space)
    """
    return """First line (no leading spaces)
 Second line (one leading space)"""
```